# how to navigate one page to another in iphone and android using titanium studio

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am fresher in titanium for mac os x.

I am using titanium first time and do not have any knowledge on js pages and action event's

I am setup titanium and add button. On button click i need to navigate to another js page

and this project will run into iPhone and android device

Comment: please help me for this

Comment: Are you using alloy?

Answer (score 0):

if you are newbie then [kitchensink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) is best practice to learn titanium.

Answer (score 0):

in app.js file write

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'red'
});
win.open();
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'click me to open new window'
});
win.add(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var newWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url : 'newWindow.js',
        backgroundColor : 'white'
    });
    newWindow.open();
});
```